# WPF WebBrowser HTMLDocument

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to inject some javascript code to prevent javascript error popup, but I cannot find `HTMLDocument` and `IHTMLScriptElement` in WPF:

```
var doc = browser.Document as HTMLDocument;

if (doc != null)
{
    //Create the sctipt element 
    var scriptErrorSuppressed = (IHTMLScriptElement)doc.createElement("SCRIPT");
    scriptErrorSuppressed.type = "text/javascript";
    scriptErrorSuppressed.text = m_disableScriptError;
    //Inject it to the head of the page 
    IHTMLElementCollection nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("head");
    foreach (IHTMLElement elem in nodes)
    {
        var head = (HTMLHeadElement)elem;
        head.appendChild((IHTMLDOMNode)scriptErrorSuppressed);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 21):

To clarify, `Microsoft.mshtml` isn't the 'using', it's a reference.

Full solution:

1. Add a project reference to `Microsoft.mshtml`
2. Add `using mshtml;`

Answer (score 7):

I have solved the problem by using:

```
Microsoft.mshtml;
```