# Interop type 'mshtml.HTMLHeadElementClass' cannot be embedded

Tags: c#, wpf, dom

Any clue how to resolve this error?

```
 void wb_LoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
             var doc = (mshtml.HTMLDocument)wb.Document;

             HTMLHeadElementClass head = (HTMLHeadElementClass)((IHTMLElementCollection)doc.all.tags("head")).item(null, 0); // Error

             IHTMLScriptElement scriptObject = (IHTMLScriptElement)doc.createElement("script");
             scriptObject.type = @"text/javascript";
             scriptObject.text = @"function btn1_OnClick(str){alert('you clicked' + str);}";

             head.appendChild((IHTMLDOMNode)scriptObject); 
}
```

Comment: Leaving this as a comment since in the case of mshtml it is probably not the proper way to resolve the error, but the quick way to resolve an "interop type cannot be embedded" error is to turn off "Embed Interop Types" in the properties menu for the reference itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could found the  solution here

[WPF WebBrowser HTMLDocument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12834742/wpf-webbrowser-htmldocument)

Don't forget to refer to `Microsoft.mshtml`

Answer (score 1):

The synthetic COM interop classes whose name end with "Class" are not embeddable.  The "Embed Interop Types" feature (aka "nopia") only supports embedding interface and coclass types that actually appear in the type library.

Use the interface type instead, mshtml.IHTMLHeadElement.  Like you did for IHTMLScriptElement.